# Thread doesn't seem to be running in the background

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asynchronous, .net-4.0

I have the following code:

```
public class BaseControlClass : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected delegate void AsyncronousAction();
    protected virtual void FAsyncEvent() { } //Overidden on derived classes.

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            FPerformAsyncronousTasks(FAsyncEvent);
    }

    protected virtual void FPerformAsyncronousTasks(AsyncronousAction AsyncCallback)
    {
        new Thread(delegate()
        {
            AsyncCallback();
        }).Start();
    }
}

public class DerivedControlClass : BaseClass
{
    protected override void FAsyncEvent()
    {
        //Contact web service, wait for results, add to local database.
    }
}
```

What I was expecting is for the page to load and the code in `FAsyncEvent()` in my derived class to run behind the scenes however, the page doesn't finish loading until the code in `FAsyncEvent()` has completed.

Am I doing something wrong with the threading here?

**EDIT** Strangely, I have noticed if I do a Clean -> Build then run the code, it works fine and the page finishes loading whilst the web service is being contacted. Subsequent runs though mean the page waits until the thread has finished processing.

Comment: Nothing looks wrong, atleast for me.

Comment: It looks ok, if you do it all in the page load (rather than the extra method call) does it work? i.e. `if (!Page.IsPostBack) new Thread(delegate() { FAsyncEvent(); }).Start();`

Comment: I'll give that a go James. My example here is a little simpler than my actual setup so it could be elsewhere so I dig around a little bit.

Comment: Do you use `Invoke` somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code keeps the reference to the UserControl alive, which *might* be preventing the request from continuing. Try passing a static method to the new thread, just as a quick check and see if it helps.

Comment: @Luan - Can you see my edit, do you think your answer would explain this behaviour?

Comment: It might. By default, ASP.NET tries to make the request appear single threaded. That also means that anytime you use something shared between two requests from the same user (such as Session), it automatically uses locks to make sure that nothing bad happens. So if you've got a Session operation running in the background thread and you try to use Session in the page, it will have to wait for the background thread to finish. If that's the case, you could just pass all the Session values to the method you're executing - again, having the method static helps a lot against unwanted locking.

Comment: @Luan - Thanks for the explanation and it could actually be the sessions in my case, I will take a look. I can't really use static classes at the moment as I want to be able to override them but we'll see.

Comment: If you want to keep instances, just make sure they aren't UserControls or Pages and such. It means a bit more boilerplate code, but it should still be manageable - just add a virtual GetAsyncWorker method to your base class, which will return the actual (simple) class that has the method you want called - without any ASP.NET strings attached.

Comment: I had some objects I was passing around which were shared between controls. After reading your post about sessions, I tried re-instantiating these instead which seems to have solved the issue. Many thanks for your time and detailed explanations.